# PHPで画像の特定1ドットの色を取得したい

Tags: php

phpで簡単な画像処理を行っています。
そこで、特定の1ドットの色(RGB)を取得する必要が出てきたのですが、これは実現可能でしょうか。
自分でもマニュアルを参照してみましたが、それらしい関数は見当たりません。
一体どうすれば取得できるのでしょうか。
ちなみに、利用しているのはGDライブラリです。

Comment: [PHP: imagecolorat](http://jp2.php.net/manual/ja/function.imagecolorat.php)

Comment: @argus 回答ありがとうございます。恐縮ですが、コメントではなく回答として投稿していただけないでしょうか?コメントはマークすることができませんので...

Comment: ご自身で回答を投稿することもできますよ(マークも可能)。できればそうしていただけると助かります(いや、本音を言えば回答するのが単に面倒くさいだけなのですが)。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

argusさんのコメントから引用させていただきます。

> [PHP: imagecolorat](https://www.php.net/manual/ja/function.imagecolorat.php)